# getting stuck on Create account while creating a realtime database in Firebase, i am making an ecommerce app

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an ecommerce app, getting stuck on create account, at the loadingbar which says "Please wait, while we are checking credentials"..while creating a realtime database in firebase.

I have tried to create a realtime database

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username, pass, phonenumber ;
    Button createaccount;
    ProgressDialog loadingbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        phonenumber = findViewById(R.id.reg_phone_number);
        createaccount=findViewById(R.id.create_account);
        loadingbar=new ProgressDialog(this);


        createaccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CreateAccount();

            }
        });
}

    private void CreateAccount() {
        String name = username.getText().toString();
        String phone = phonenumber.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
        {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Please enter name...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))

        {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Please enter phone...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))

        {
            Toast.makeText(register.this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else
        {
            loadingbar.setTitle("Create Account");
            loadingbar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are checking the credentials..");
            loadingbar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingbar.show();

            Validatephonenumber(name,phone,password);
        }
}

    private void Validatephonenumber(final String name, final String phone, final String password) {

        final DatabaseReference RootRef ;
        RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        RootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(phone).exists())){

                    HashMap<String,Object> userdatamap = new HashMap<>();
                    userdatamap.put("phone",phone);
                    userdatamap.put("name",name);
                    userdatamap.put("password",password);

                    RootRef.child("Users").child(phone).updateChildren(userdatamap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "Congratulations, Your account has been created..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingbar.dismiss();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(register.this,login.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                loadingbar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "Network Error, Please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "This "+ phone + "already exists..." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingbar.dismiss();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(register.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Account should have been created in firebase.

Comment: The first step is to not leave `onCancelled` empty, as it may be hiding problems. The minimal implementation is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: After that, what happens inside `Validatephonenumber` if you run the code in a debugger? Does the `onDataChange` get called? If so, what happens if you step through that method? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: 2019-07-22 09:43:40.821 12533-12533/com.example.ecommerce W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: doesnt seem to work :/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
package com.example.qaseem.app56;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class signup extends  AppCompatActivity {
    public Button b1;
    public EditText inputname,password,Phone;
    public ProgressDialog loadingbar;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);

            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbb1);
            inputname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed3);
            Phone= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);
            loadingbar = new ProgressDialog(this);


            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    createAccount();

                }
            });
        }

    private void createAccount() {

        String name = inputname.getText().toString();

        String pass =password.getText().toString();

        String Phone1 = Phone.getText().toString();




        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"write your nam",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

      else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"write your encrypted password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Phone1))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"write your Phone",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

else
        {
            loadingbar.setTitle("Create Account");

            loadingbar.setMessage("Please Wait, while we are checking the credentials");
            loadingbar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            loadingbar.show();
            ValidatephoneNumber(name,pass,Phone1);
        }



    }

    private void ValidatephoneNumber(final String name, final String pass, final String Phone1) {
        final DatabaseReference Rootref;
        Rootref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Rootref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!(dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(Phone1).exists()))
                {
                    HashMap<String,Object> userdataMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userdataMap.put("phone",Phone1);
                    userdataMap.put("password",pass);
                            userdataMap.put("name",name);

                            Rootref.child("Users").child(Phone1).updateChildren(userdataMap)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Congraduation your Account has been created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingbar.dismiss();

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this,login.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                loadingbar.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "This" +Phone1 + "Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    loadingbar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Try Another phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(signup.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Avoid answering questions with just code, try to provide additional information such as what the core problem is and how your code fixes said issue.

Comment: Thanks for your code, but it doesnt seem to work, still stuck on checking the credential..please let me know where i am wrong!!

Comment: send me your project at kqaseem75@gmail.com i will fix it for you.

Comment: Simran kaur did you change the rules for database